# flutter_blue how to stop connect()?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

```
device.connect(autoConnect: false).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5),
           onTimeout: () {
         print("flutter ble time out");
         
       })
```

I want to stop this function befor the time out,how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout will happen after 5 seconds, so before that, if we want to disconnect the connection, use the below code, call it from any button press, see it should work.

```
device.disconnect();
```

Also, if you want to stop search use

```
FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan()
```

Comment: thanks for you answer,this function is disconnect bluetooth in my understanding,I want to stop connecting,will it work?

Comment: yes it should, also if you want to stop search use FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan(),